# Table styling not matching documentation examples

Tags: bootstrap-4, html-table, drupal, css-tables

When I copy the sample table from Bootstrap's documentation, the [styling rendered](https://wilmettewatch.com/table-test) doesn't match [the style shown in the examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/).

Here's what the example table is supposed to look like:
[image: Intended style]

But instead renders like this:
[image: Rendered style]

I played around with the different styling classes, and they each appear to do something, but they don't render as documented. I verified that the documentation version I'm looking at matches the version linked to in my source `<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`

If pertinent, I'm using Drupal with a Bootstrap Barrio custom sub-theme.

Why don't the tables render as documented?

Comment: It's hard to tell with no code to look at. It would be great if you could share it. Considering that you're using Drupal with a theme, I'd say that your theme contains CSS overrides for Bootstrap's tables. Your theme's CSS would be loaded after the Bootstrap CSS and would therefore override it.

Comment: Yes, just as you wrote this I figured it out; it was indirectly a Drupal theme issue. The Bootsrap Barrio theme has elaborate (and ugly) table css overrides. I'll answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is additional CSS that is overriding Bootstrap's default table appearance. The Bootstrap Barrio theme adds various table styling in its `css/componenets/table.css`.

To eliminate some or all of the custom table styling, edit your sub-theme's `info.yml` and `libraries.yml` files or copy and edit the `table.css` file to your liking.